# Why is my macros working in a workbook but not in PERSONAL.XLSB?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a macros on a worksheet that sets the cells within a dynamic range to "0". It works great. I want this code to be available for use on other worksheets so I added the working code to my PERSONAL.XLSB.  When I copy that same code to PERSONAL.XLSB it does not work. Not even on the original worksheet that it had worked on because I moved the code to Personal.XLSB

I have other macros in Personal.xlsb that works so I know I'm utilizing my personal macros workbook correctly.

```
Sub Zero()       
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
         Application.ScreenUpdating = False
         ws.Range("AA16:AA" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "0"
End Sub
```

This code causes all of the Cells, starting at AA16 down to the last cell with content to be set to "0". Hooray! When this code is copied to Personal.xlsb, it does nothing.

I don't get an error message, just nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at row #3 where you are setting the value of variable ws. If you put breakpoint on that line and use your debugger you'll see that the program does not recognize 'Sheet1' or at least not as you want it to (as a instance of Worksheet object) (see the image bellow).

[image]

The solution to this depends on what you need. You can simply replace 'Sheet1' with `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet`, this way the macro will change the content in column AA for active worksheet. See the code below:

```
Sub Zero()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
         Application.ScreenUpdating = False
         ws.Range("AA16:AA" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "0"
End Sub
```

Comment: You are welcome. You can mark the answer if it solved your problem :)